# AlertDialog как правильно использовать Navigator.of(context).pop()?

Tags: flutter, dart

Пояснение, что делает приложение. Происходит нажатие на кнопку **Show**. Появляется диалоговое окно. Если в нем нажать **Ok**, появляется текст, название кнопки изменятся на **Hide**, если нажать **Cancel**, то текст не появляется, название кнопки остается прежним. Если нажать на **Hide**, текст исчезает. Все просто.

Дальше будет полный приведен код. Все работает.

Что мне не понятно. Если в код поместить вызов функции, все нормально работает

```
Navigator.of(context).pop( _f2() );
```

Если поместить реализацию этой функции, происходит ошибка, подчеркнута первая точка с запятой

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(
 _b = true;
 _visible = true;
 _text = 'Hide';
);
```

Если поместить реализацию этой функции в setState ошибки не происходит, работает нормально

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(
 setState(() {
   _b = true;
   _visible = true;
   _text = 'Hide';
  })
);
```

Если поместить анонимную функцию, ошибки нет, но текст не появляется

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(
 () {
   _b = true;
   _visible = true;
   _text = 'Hide';
 }
);
```

Все дело в **setState** ?
Подскажите, как вообще правильно сделать? Спасибо.

Вот полный код.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _text;
 bool _visible;
 bool _b;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _text = 'Show';
  _visible = false;
  _b = false;
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {
   switch(_b) {
    case false:
     _showAlertDialog1();
     break;
    case true:
     _b = false;
     _visible = false;
     _text = 'Show';
     break;
   }
  });
 }

 void _f2() {
  setState(() {
   _b = true;
   _visible = true;
   _text = 'Hide';
  });
 }

 Future<void> _showAlertDialog1() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
   context: context,
   barrierDismissible: false,
   builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
     title: Text(
      'SHOW TEXT!'
     ),
     content: Text(
      'Show text now'
     ),
     actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
       onPressed: () {

        //все нормально работает
        Navigator.of(context).pop( _f2() );

        //происходит ошибка, подчеркнута первая точка с запятой
        /*Navigator.of(context).pop(
         _b = true;
         _visible = true;
         _text = 'Hide';
        );*/

        //ошибки не происходит, работает нормально
        /*Navigator.of(context).pop(
         setState(() {
          _b = true;
          _visible = true;
          _text = 'Hide';
         })
        );*/

        //ошибки нет, но текст не появляется
        /*Navigator.of(context).pop(
         () {
          _b = true;
          _visible = true;
          _text = 'Hide';
         }
        );*/

       },
       child: Text(
        'Ok',
       ),
      ),
      FlatButton(
       onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
       },
       child: Text(
        'Cancel',
       ),
      ),
     ],
    );
   }
  );
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
     child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
       onPressed: () { _f1(); },
       splashColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
       ),
       child: Text(
        _text,
        style: TextStyle(
         color: Colors.deepPurple,
         fontSize: 20.0,
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: Visibility(
      visible: _visible,
      child: Text(
       'Hello World!',
       style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.pink,
        fontSize: 36.0,
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начало надо посмотреть что из себя представляет `setState`:

```
void setState(void Function() fn)
```

А теперь из чего состоит `(){}` (анонимная функция):

```
void Function() // более подробно: void *без названия*(){}
```

А теперь вопрос: заметили сходства между `setState` и `(){}`?

*Ответ: это обе `void` функции.*

---

А теперь к `Navigator.of(context).pop()`, посмотри из чего состоит `pop`:

```
void pop<T extends Object>([T result])
```

`T` (т.е. дженерик) наследуемый от `Object`.

Следовательно когда мы отправляем туда функцию (например _f1 из вашего примера), то данный `pop` становиться таким:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop<void>(_f1()) // более подробно: void pop<void>([void result])
```

---

И последний вопрос: почему анонимная функция не обновляет состояние виджета?
Потому что у `StatefulWidget` обновлять состояние виджета может только `setState`.

Но не следует путать **состояние виджета** и **состояние переменой**, переменная будет обновлять свое состояние всегда, в то время как виджету нужно дать команду (`setState`) для перерисовки с новыми данными => обновить состояние виджета.

---

Почему тут ошибка:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop( _b = true; _visible = true; _text = 'Hide'; );
```

Вы спутали параметр с блоком кода.

---

***Правильный вариант**: который работает как вам нужно.*

Comment: Уважаемый MiT! Спасибо Вам большое. Непонятно, почему здесь ошибка? Navigator.of(context).pop(
 _b = true;
 _visible = true;
 _text = 'Hide';
);

Comment: @Anton у функции `pop` единственный параметр, а вы туда пытаетесь впихнуть блок кода, язык просто не понимает что вы пытаетесь сделать)

Comment: Понял, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Если будут вопросы спрашивайте!)